# Azure App Service cannot get the contents of my app via GitHub Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

#### Problem definition

I am developing ASP.NET MVC 7 application. I want to enable CI/CD, however this is my first use of Azure services. I tried to create App Service through Azure portal and enable Github actions (standard .yaml workflow that is automatically set by Azure). Everything succeeded.

```yaml
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - YouInvestMe

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '7.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'YouInvestMe'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: .
```

However, when to access the website via ***.azurewebsites.net, it says the webapp is running and waiting for my content.

I have tried to check over all files that are in `/home/site/wwwroot/` and mostly they are .dll files. Accessing the terminal with Web SSH, I even tried running the main .dll with `dotnet` command, and it worked but on **localhost:5000**, so I couldn't see.

#### Q: How can I configure/deploy my project so that app get live and CI enabled with database schema update on every push?

**N.B.** The project uses MySQL database, and it is set up and running on Azure. Connection strings are fine.

Here's what I get:

[image: Problem]

This is latest deployment via GitHub Actions
[image: Lates logs]

If there is not enough info, I will edit the question.

Comment: Before this, there was a persistent error for every workflow: `Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.` Then, I deleted App Service on Azure and recreated again with new workflow. Now it says waiting for content.

Comment: In `Azure App Service` => `Configuratuion` =>`Default Documents`, remove all the available documents and add a new document `Index.cshtml`.

Comment: So as per now, my application started working when I deployed on Windows instead of targeting Linux while creating App Service. However, I want to understand how this works. In `Default Documents` I found a list of default names: **Default.htm
Default.html
Default.asp
index.htm
index.html
iisstart.htm
default.aspx
index.php
hostingstart.html**. And my application still works under these configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed the `ASP.NET MVC7 App` to Azure App service using GitHub Actions.

Initially even I got the same Content page.

[image]

If we got the content page, it means that our App is deployed successfully, but there is no default page to serve the app.

- In the deployed `Azure App Service` => `Configuratuion` =>`Default Documents`,  add a new document `Index.cshtml`.

[image]

- All the deployed `files/folders` will be under `wwwroot` directory.

> I have tried to check over all files that are in `/home/site/wwwroot/` and mostly they are .dll files.

- Once the Application is deployed, all the files are compiled into `dll` files. You cannot find any of the forms/files (Controllers/.cshtml) directly.

***My deployed Project folder Structure***
[image]

- If you still get any issue, update the `web.config` file in the Kudu Console `wwwroot` directory(stdoutLogEnabled `false` to `true`).

```cs
 <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SimpleWebAppMVC.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

- Now try to access the Url,a log file will be created with the clear error description in `wwwroot` => `logs` folder.

[image]

> How can I configure/deploy my project so that app get live and CI enabled with database schema update on every push?

- In `Azure Portal`, while creating `Azure App Service`, enable the `GitHub Actions settings`  while creating the `App Service` itself.
- This option enables to continuously deploy the app whenever new change/commit is done in the repository.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for thorough step-by-step explanation. Just to clarify, is the root of the problem under **Default Documents** in **Configuration** settings?

Comment: Yes..I have cleared it by adding the default document.

Comment: Even you can set default doc in `web.config` file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using the Azure-generated GitHub Action workflow.

I came to the conclusion, that script generated doesn't behave correctly when your solution has many projects.

In my scenario, once I created a Test project inside the solution, the deployment had that result.

Why? Because the `dotnet publish` step doesn't specify the project.

So this:

```
- name: dotnet publish
  run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

Should be this:

```
- name: dotnet publish
  run: dotnet publish MyApplication/MyApplication.csproj -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```