# Deploying ASP.NET Core MVC app to Azure Web App Service gives "Your web app is running and waiting for your content"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I am new to deploying web apps.

I recently finished working on a project I wanted to deploy to Azure. I used VS to publish it an Azure App Service with a GitHub CI/CD Workflow but when I try to access it I am getting the following page:

[image: error page]

I have absolutely no clue why. Everything in the process went smoothly but the page is not showing. I could really use some help!

I searched around for this error but I couldn't find anything. I also tried different deployment strategies to no avail.

EDIT: turns out that my project files are not getting copied to the app service.

EDIT 2: I got the app running with a zip deploy but Id still like to use GitHub Actions to automate it

Comment: Does this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74623681/19648279) answer your question.Chcek the default documents as mentioned in the given link.

Comment: As I know, you should submit your code to github and if will auto delpoy your webapp if you have configured the CI/CD Workflow.  Could you share more details about your .yml file ?

Comment: @Harshitha I do not have the default document tab for some reason

Comment: A little update, I got the app running with a zip deploy but id still like to use GitHub Actions to automate it

Comment: @JasonPan here is the YAML https://github.com/vassdeniss/EasyRank-Web-App/blob/main/.github/workflows/EasyRank.yml

Comment: You can read my answer carefully, it will be very helpful. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you create the .yml file. I generate it by default, you can check below. It it will deploy failed and don't worry.

[image]

Then you will find the .yml file generated under your github repo. Please find it and copy the below script and paste there. Don't forget replace the `app-name`, `publish-profile` and so on.

Then it will auto deploy again, now it should be deployed successfully. If not, try to modify anything, and deploy again for testing. You can see I add `Azure Web App-01` in the first line.

The script I have tested and it works well like below.

[image]

[image]

Then we will find the publish file under the wwwroot. The scm site is :

```
https://app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui
```

[image]

Then we should add startup command in azure portal.

[image]

Then the application should works well in your side.

*It not works in my side, after investigating the reason,I found it missing the connectionstring and other configurations, so it not works in my side.*

#### .yml script

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App-01 - WebApplication920221114163713

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: WebApplication920221114163713
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: .
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: EasyRank

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build  -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp


  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'WebApplication920221114163713'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAP***0A789F0B31 }}
          package: .
```

Comment: It appears my earlier comment didn't post. Anyway I tried and even though it deployed my code to azure I'm getting a weird error which is:  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)2022-12-13T18:55:52.054183398Z File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Comment: @vassdeniss I have download your repo and I also haven't seen you have install this package, pls install it and update your repo. It should works.

Comment: @vassdeniss And it's a different issue.

Comment: Ill open a new issue yeah. This one is solved